# How can I selectively access a subset of a Spreadsheet with the Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to do selective manipulation of large spreadsheets with the Drive API?
We're dealing with some huge spreadhseets that might have many dozens of tabs, and might be many megabytes in size.

Given that the older gdata APIs are deprecated, is there a way to process large spreadsheets with the Drive API?

Answer (score 0):

1) with gdata style API (the non-deprecated bit). Selective reads/writes are easy enough, but inserts are not so easy. Insert row/col requires you to move all the other cells downs/right with code (updating all cell refs).

2) Max cells is 400,000 for a google spreadsheet, Max size 20MB. http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603

3) Also look at Google-apps-script, while, my humble opinion, it is a bit slower, and not very end users/non-programmer friendly, it does have good quality docs and a rich set of functions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean the non depracated gdata API ?

Apps script doesn't serve our needs because we are writing a server application.

Comment: The v3 spreadsheet api is more of less the same as gdata api, with a few changes. v3 docs: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ example code:https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/ DrEdit tutorial is also good for understanding OAuth2

Comment: You can call Google-apps-script code over the web (http) and pass parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Eddy. Isn't the spreadsheet API deprecated though ?

+1 for apps script being accessible over HTTP, will definitely investigate that.

Comment: only v1 & v2 are deprecated, v3 is active, see link above. You are the 2nd person to make that comment, wonder why people are jumping to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: Alright - I just read it, and I think you're right. I was (incorrectly ) assuming the deprecation of Documents List 3.0 to also applied to Spreadsheets 3.0.

The other reason why I guess I extrapolated this was because the Gdata and Drive APIs just seem different, and I expected there to be a newer cleaner "Drive like" API to go with spreadsheets as well. As it stands, the objects used by the APIs have to be manually converted over, they have different auth scopes and so on.